# xpath get html for persian chars

Tags: php, xpath, unicode, persian

I get the inner html for Persian web page with this method :

```
private static function getInnerHTML($node)
{
    $innerHTML = "";
    $children = $node->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
        $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($child,true));
        $innerHTML .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML();
    }
    return $innerHTML;
}
```

When I see the source in browser, I found the Persian characters as below :

`&#1711;&#1586;&#1575;&#1585;&#1588;`

What can I do to convert this coding to regular Persian characters?

For example this chars must be :
`گزارش`

Sorry, I don't know what is this coding, so I can't search for it before.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `$innerHTML .= html_entity_decode($tmp_doc->saveHTML());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment what you need is [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode).

```
$innerHTML .= html_entity_decode($tmp_doc->saveHTML());
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mAeSP4)**.